# Can't access data within returned JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a function that returns this piece of information as follows:

```
return json_encode(["id" => 0]);
```

also tried

```
return json_encode(array("id" => 0));
```

and

```
return json_encode(array("id" => 0), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Within the calling function I stored the returned value in the $var variable. I then try to access the "id" element as follows:

```
$var->id
```

I get a *Trying to get property of non-object* error.

I checked on php.net and on different questions on Stackoverflow but can't find the solution.

Comment: why is it json encoded at all?

Comment: If I return it as an array without json_encode I still can't access it with $var->id

Comment: something wrong with `$var['id']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `var_dump`'ing the return value. `json_encode` returns JSON as a string that can then be parsed into an object or array. If `$var` is the result of `json_encode` then you cannot access any properties of the encoded data without parsing it first.

Based on your revised question:

It seems like what you are really trying to do is cast an array to an object. All you need to do to accomplish that is:

```
$var = (object) ['id' => 0];
```

The `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag converts arrays to objects *and encodes them as such*. The result is still a JSON string. If you were to call `json_decode` on that string you would have an object, but that is not the correct way to cast an array to an object.